# Call Google Map Javascript API from python

Tags: javascript, python

i would like to call this method from Google Maps Javascript API:
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(origin, destination) from python, not from javascript. How can I do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Did you find an answer? I´m trying to the same and it seems that I´ll have to learn Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library called [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Sample request:

```
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

A short [tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/) you could use

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how to use it with this specific Javascript API ?

Comment: You can try using https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

Comment: Thanks. I already took a look on it, unfortunately, it does not contain the spherical library.